# WPF Datagrid: Color entire row or first cell in row based on cell values

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to color a row or  if better simply just the first cell in the row to a color based on the containing value for all the cells in that row.

I can't get it to work and it seems like the index is not correct and for some reason it does not match.

I am using autogenerated columns and feed the datagrid with a class. I am not able to use databinding, since the datagrid gets all data filled from a class.

This is how it is done.
datagrid.ItemsSource = Myclass.MyModel;

My class contains multiple properties, The first 4 columns comes from the class as string properties and the rest of the columns are from an ObservableCollection.

Always color the first cell in the first column if the cells in the same row (except for the first 4 cells) are different from eachother. So what I mean by this, is that they should never be colored if all the values are "Base".

This is what I am trying:

```
    public void HighlightVariants()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var row in datagrid.Items)
        {
            i++;
            List<string> rowvalues = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataGridColumn column in datagrid.Columns)
            {
                if (column.GetCellContent(row) is TextBlock)
                {
                    TextBlock cellContent = column.GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                    rowvalues.Add(cellContent.Text);
                }
            }
            rowvalues.RemoveRange(0, Math.Min(4, rowvalues.Count));

            if (rowvalues.Any(o => o != rowvalues[0]) || rowvalues.Any(a => a == "DNI"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
                DataGridRow drow = DataGridMiscHelpers.GetRow(datagrid, i);
                drow.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }

        }
    }
```

GetRow looks like this:

```
    public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid grid, int index)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null)
        {
            grid.UpdateLayout();
            grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
            row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }
        return row;
    }
```

I could really use some help on this.
Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you do it in XAML.
Using Styles in XAML and coverters this could be solved much easier.

Comment: @EldHasp Could you try to give an example on it using XAML and converters? Im quite new to WPF.

Comment: What type are you populating the DataGrid.ItemsSorce collection with?
You have two values for `ItemsSource =" {Binding Data.DefaultView} "datagrid.ItemsSource = Myclass.MyModel;` and I can't figure it out.
And describe in more detail how the color depends on the property values of the collection item.

Comment: @EldHasp My mistake I edited some of the text hopefully it makes more sense. I am populating the datagrid using: datagrid.ItemsSource = Myclass.MyModel; 

My class contains multiple properties, The first 4 columns comes from the class as string properties and the rest of the columns are from an ObservableCollection. 

Always color the first cell in the first column if the cells in the same row (except for the first 4 cells) are different from eachother. So what I mean by this, is that they should never be colored if all the values are "Base".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change row background or foreground based on your class please set `LoadingRow="LoadingRow"` event for your datagrid in XAML,

and in code behind:

```
    private void LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e){

        var row = e.Row;
        YourClass ch = row.DataContext as YourClass;
        if (ch != null)
        {
            if (sender == yourDataGrid)
            {
                if (some condition 1)
                {
                    row.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    row.Foreground = Brushes.White;
                }
                else if (some condition 2)
                {
                    row.Background = Brushes.Green;
                    row.Foreground = Brushes.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.Background = Brushes.Tranparent;
                    row.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to change cell colors based on it's content:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="JohnDoe">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer!
I implemented loadingRow, and it is working for the first time i open the datagrid. 
As soon as I start scrolling it starts to randomly give rows colors, seems like the index or something is messing with me, do you have any idea on why it does that?

Comment: @BenjaminMadsen Hi, i had same problem in last. for this problem you should use else statement like that i provided in answer. this ```else``` tell your program that if another conditions not true , run this. Now i am using this both method on my project and working vey well.

Comment: Thank you, it is working :)

Just a simple side question, would it be possible to color the first cell only using LoadingRow event?

Comment: @BenjaminMadsen please see second section of answer, based your class ojbect it colorized cells. for example if ```FirstName``` is JohnDoe cell background color changed to DodgerBlue.also ```LoadingRow``` is for rows not for cell. if you mean something else let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The information provided is not sufficient for an accurate answer.
Therefore, I am giving a demo code.

Entity class and class with their collection:

```
    public class Texts
    {
        public string Text1 { get; set; }
        public string Text2 { get; set; }
        public string Text3 { get; set; }
        public string Text4 { get; set; }
        public string Text5 { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Myclass
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<Texts> MyModel { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Texts>()
        {
            new Texts() {Text1="123", Text2="45678", Text3="90qwer", Text4="tyuiio", Text5="as"},
            new Texts() {Text1="asad", Text2="gfg", Text3="hkjhk", Text4="kl", Text5="fgfhgf"}
        };
    }
```

A converter that takes an entity instance, parses that instance and returns a brush (color) as the parse result:

```
    public class TextsToBrushConveretr : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //Getting an item(row) of the collection.
            if (value is Texts texts)
            {
                //Here's some sort of processing on the resulting row.

                // Example
                return texts.Text1.Length < 4
                    ? Brushes.LightPink
                    : Brushes.LightGreen;
            }

            //Return value in case of invalid binding.
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>An instance of the converter to avoid creating a new one every time and making it easier to use in XAML.</summary>
        public static TextsToBrushConveretr Instance { get; } = new TextsToBrushConveretr();
    }
```

Usage in XAML:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Myclass.MyModel}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text1}" Header="Text1">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={x:Static local:TextsToBrushConveretr.Instance}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text2}" Header="Text2"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text3}" Header="Text3"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text4}" Header="Text4"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text5}" Header="Text5"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you @ELDHasp for the answer, but I can't do it this way, since i am using AutoGenerateColumns="True". Basicly the itemsource is just a collection, and I don't know how many columns there are in this collection.

Comment: You will show the implementation of the collection item type.
It is not clear from your explanation how you will get a variable number of columns.